# What is the font used inthe Pocket logo?

Tags: fonts, typography, font-identification

What font is used in this logo? I'd love to have this or a similar one.

[image]

Comment: The mix of flat and rounded serifs and the weird tail of the t makes me believe it's modified which is likely for a wordmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an exact match, but these two have a sort of similar style:

**[Kaleko 205 Round](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/talbot/kaleko-205-round/)**

[image]

**[Booster Next FY](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontyou/booster-next-fy/)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks similar to the following font.

[Tzaristane B Normal](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typotheticals/tzaristane/b-normal/):

[image]
[image]
[image]

Probably you also know this, you can use the "what the font" tool to identify a font from an image.

[What the font](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/)

Comment: t does not match